# Query on Nested Array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

In Mongodb, i have two documents tryout collection in db.

```
{a:[1,2,[1,2,3],4,5]}, {a:[1,2,3,9,13]}
```

How I can get all the documents in which 2nd element is 3 or array as 2nd element contains 3?
I have tried `db.tryout.find({"a.2":3})` and it's returning only 2nd document.

## MyLogic

I have three docs in abc collection.

```
{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:[1,3]}
```

"`db.abc.find{a:1}`"
this query will return doc1 and doc3
So query here is checking for element or element inside array if there is array.

I'm doing nearly same but still i'm not getting result.

I would like to know the reason behind it that why MongoDB is not searching inside array if you have used "`array.index`":val to get document

Comment: Aside from an acemic excerice, what exactly are the practical uses for nesting an array within an array randomly as in your example? Sort of wondering that beyond your own personal curiosity, why this even needs to be solved. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Thank you neil for your guidance. But i just want to know the logic behind how query executes for nested array.

Comment: `.find({  "$or": [ { "a.2": 3 }, { "a.2.0": { "$exists": true }, "a.2": { "$elemMatch": { "eq": 3 } }}]  })` or even `.find({  "$or": [ { "a.2": 3 }, { "a": { "$elemMatch": { "2": 3 } } }] })`, is the basic logic here. Neither document can be selected by the "same" conditions, due to how matching a value in an array element basically works, so it's always an `$or` condition to cater for the differences. There are other questions about the `$elemMatch` on index thing, but you're basically asking something "too specific" for questions that generally hang around here.

Comment: Both queries are returning only document without array as 2nd element. The second document written in question.

Comment: Dude it works for me, and I'm simply copying your own data from the question. Anyhow just pointing you on your way. It's academic and not of any intrinsic value since nobody actually does anything like this. Work it out for yourself. Or more to the point, work out why that actually does work.